# Form to pull page elements using file_get_contents and getElementsByClassName in PHP

Tags: php, getelementsbyname

I'm attempting to create a page where I input a url and the PHP code uses that to pull page elements from another website to be displayed on my blog post. I haven't even made it as far as the form, right now I just need to understand how to get this code to work so that it displays the page elements within the div with the class "products-grid first odd".

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('website');
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
$dochtml->getElementsByClassName('products-grid first odd');
echo ????
?>
```

Comment: Is `$strhtml` supposed to be `$homepage`? (or vice versa?)

Comment: This question is not very clear. Please demonstrate your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) object does not appear to have the method `getElementsByClassName()`.

Instead, I think you would have to `getElementsByTagName()` and then loop through those [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and `getAttribute('class')` on each and check until you find the right one.